# Можно ли сказать о колёсиках в часах, что они "идут"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли сказать о колёсиках в часах, что они "идут"? Например:

"Внутри у них колесики вращаются, идут,

свивают нитку длинную из маленьких минут".

Answer (score 1):

Определённо идут, цепляясь зубчиками, вращающиеся шестерёнки. Они внешне, из-за малой величины и шага, схожи с колёсиками. В этом смысле слово приемлемо.

Answer (score 1):

**Выражение не самое удачное.**

Хотя ***идти*** — это многозначное слово, и в данном случае оно связано с выражением *время идет*, но к вращательном движению оно обычно не применяется (если только в выражении *голова идет кругом)*.

Идти — это в общем случае двигаться, перемещаться, но обычно поступательно (даже в условном значении, если мы говорим о времени).

Можно поставить кавычки: **колесики "идут"** (то есть они-то вращаются, но при этом отсчитывают время, которое идет).

Или списать на неточность, допустимую в детских стихах (кавычки как бы подразумеваются).

Answer (score 1):

*Чёрная стрелка проходит циферблат.

Быстро, как белки, колёсики спешат.

Скачут минуты среди забот и дел.

Идут, идут, идут, идут — и месяц
пролетел!*
В. Лебедев-Кумач. [**Песенка о стрелках**](http://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/897/song/)

В этом известном  песенном четверостишии, мне кажется, идёт-движется всё: стрелка идёт-проходит, колесики идут-спешат, минуты идут-скачут.
Обо всём сказано образно — и всем понятно.

В Вашем тексте можно соединить оба глагола (вращаются-идут или вращаются-бегут), чтобы показать одновременность двух действий.

**Дополнение**

Образных описаний движения часовых колёсиков предостаточно:

*И поступь и голос у времени тише

Всех шорохов, всех голосов.

**Шуршат и работают тайно**, как мыши,

Колесики наших часов.*
С. Маршак

*И Афоня стал ожидать. Часы-ходики тикали, и колёсики их **поскрипывали и напевали, баюкая деда**.*
А. Платонов. Цветок на земле

*Представьте себе: по небу плывёт солнышко, по земле течёт речка, а в раскрытых часах, которые лежат на берегу реки, **бегут зубчатые колесики**.*
[**Л. Фельдек. Про комара Коломана**](http://peskarlib.ru/l-feldek/pro-komara-kolomana/)

Comment: Минуты идут, колесики спешат или вращаются, но вот идти колесики не могут. Хотелось бы увидеть текст, где присутствует именно такое сочетание: колёса/колёсики идут..

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но к образным изображениям колесиков вопросов нет. Бегут (=спешат) - это воспринимается уже с натяжкой, а есть ли  примеры с "идут"

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном примере слово "идут" используется исключительно для рифмы. В стихотворениях и не такое можно прочесть. Здесь, видимо, мысли ребенка. Или стихотворение для детей, которые пока не знают слова "шестеренки". А колесики, конечно, вращаются.